# Accessing value from either os.environ or argparse

Tags: python, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Parse arguments.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",  action="store_true", dest="verbose")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        verbose = bool(os.environ['VERBOSE'])
    except KeyError:
        verbose = args.verbose

    print("Verbose:", verbose)
```

And I would like to find the simpler way of returning value from two different sources (either system variable or parsed argument).

Ideally I would expect to find some one-liner such as:

```
verbose = bool(os.environ['VERBOSE']) or args.verbose
```

however instead I have `KeyError` exception, therefore I had to implement exception handler.

I'm expecting the following tests to print `True` (if `verbose` is set):

```
VERBOSE=1 ./test.py
./test.py -v
```

otherwise `False`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `get` on the `os.getenv` dictionary *and* specifying `args.verbose` as the default value (2nd param of the `.get` call) will have your desired outcome:

```
import os
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",  action="store_true", dest="verbose")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    verbose = bool(os.environ.get('VERBOSE', args.verbose))

    print("Verbose:", verbose)
```

Test runs:

> ```
> $ ./test.py -v; VERBOSE=1 ./test.py ; ./test.py
> Verbose: True
> Verbose: True
> Verbose: False
> ```

Same output as your original.

Other notes:

- The comment `# Parse arguments.` was pointless
- Imports should appear on separate lines as per [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Default val... good call.

Comment: Where do I find documented `os.environ.get()`? I've tried [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), but it doesn't mention anything about the `get()` syntax. Or it's just a standard method which can be used anywhere? Update: Ok, I've found it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Answer (score 4):

When `VERBOSE=0`, the following code:

```
bool(os.getenv('VERBOSE'))
```

still returns `True`.

An alternative solution would be:

```
bool(distutils.util.strtobool(os.getenv('VERBOSE')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that Python raises a keyError whenever you access a dictionary key that is not defined. The way to avoid that error is to `get()` the key which will return `None` if the key was not set.

For the Environment in particular, there's the `os.getenv(...)` call which does essentially the same, but simpler.

As a result, your try/catch could just be:

```
verbose = args.verbose or bool(os.getenv('VERBOSE'))
```

Comment: That changes the meaning in the case where `args.verbose` is true and the environment variable `VERBOSE` is the empty string.